# Mounting Azure file share to local box

Tags: azure, azure-storage, mount, drive, fileshare

Trying mount Azure File Share to local box
net use T: \test...\share /u:AZURE\test..... AccountKey==

getting 
System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.

445 TCP is open as recommended for outside azure connections.
From Azure VM able to connect with exactly same approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ISP also could block port 445.  Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems).

To see the summary of ISPs that allow or disallow access from port 445, go to [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32346.azure-summary-of-isps-that-allow-disallow-access-from-port-445.aspx).

You could use PortQry.exe to check it.

```
PortQry.exe -n [storage account name].file.core.windows.net -p TCP -e 445
```

[image]

If your ISP block port 445, you could create a VPN connection, please refer to this [answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af1a8967-aa57-483d-afbd-0059acf02c81/tunneling-to-azure-storage-file-services?forum=windowsazuredata).

Comment: You should ensure port 445 is open(outbound) on your VM. You could use `PortQry.exe` to check it.